# Where do I place API code?

Tags: wordpress, api

I want to know where I should place API code. For example, to call [this site](https://www.hellosign.com/api/embeddedSigningWalkthrough#ServerSide) do I put the call in a PHP file? e.g.:

```
<?php

// API CODE

?>
```

Any reference would really be helpful.

Comment: according to documentation, you have to use `CURL` to send the request and get the response.

Comment: yes i saw that but my question is where do i use that or how do i basically use that

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function that use the API and place it on the functions.php file.

Comment: where exactly should i put it i did this but didnt work http://pastebin.com/hveEks71

Comment: You have to put on functions.php file